# Unable to get data from Wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wikipedia-api

I am working on a 'Wikipedia Viewer' project, where you enter a search term and see a list of Wikipedia search results, but it is **far from complete**.

Until now I have just written the code to display the first search term. But it doesn't work.

My HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="searchAndButtons">
  
<input type="text" id="search">
  <button class="btn" id="searchBut">Search</button>
   <form action="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"><button class="btn">Random Wiki Article</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="searchResults">
    </div>
  
  
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```css
.container-fluid{
  padding:5%;
}
.searchAndButtons{
  text-align:center;
}
```

My Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchBut").on("click",function(){//this is click handler
   var searchTerm=document.getElementById("#search").value;
    searchTerm=searchTerm.replace(/\s/g,"+");
    
    $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles="+searchTerm+"&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=0&rvparse=1",function(json){
       $(".searchResults").html(JSON.stringify(json));

        });
    });
  });
```

Where am I going wrong? When I run the code in Codepen and check the console, it shows an error "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null". 
My project on codepen - [link](http://codepen.io/aks2161989/pen/WxLoya)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchBut").on("click",function(){//this is click handler
   var searchTerm=document.getElementById("search").value;
    searchTerm=searchTerm.replace(/\s/g,"+");

    $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles="+searchTerm+"&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=0&rvparse=1",function(json){
       $(".searchResults").html(JSON.stringify(json));

        });
    });
  });
```

Update your JS code with this. id gets value by 'search' not '#search'

**UPDATE**: To add headers you can do the following

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#searchBut").on("click",function(){//this is click handler
       var searchTerm=document.getElementById("search").value;
        searchTerm=searchTerm.replace(/\s/g,"+");



    $.ajax({
              url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles="+searchTerm+"&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=0&rvparse=1', //your request URL
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
              error: function() { alert('boo!'); },
              beforeSend: setHeader
            });
          });

          function setHeader(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('securityCode', 'Foo'); //your header key and value
          }

        });
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still does not work. Now I get a new error in the console - "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=c&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=0&rvparse=1. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

Comment: @aks have updated my answer. Check that out to put headers you can try this out `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example` as a key and value

Comment: Is this code is a replacement for the getJSON function? Or should I add this code to my getJSON?  Sorry if the question seems silly but i am a beginner.

Comment: I tried adding the code, but I still get the 'Cross-origin-request-blocked' error on the dev console.

Comment: @aks then possible you should try checking the wikipedia API about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`